# Unable to restore complete database from pg_dump

Tags: postgresql-10, pg-dump

I ran the following command to backup my PostgreSQL database:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -W -F t crewdb > /home/chris1/Documents/crewcut/crewdb/crewdb_bak.tar
```

This file was later saved to a USB.

After installing PostgreSQL on a new Ubuntu 18.04 system I ran the following command to restore the database from the USB:

```
psql -U postgres -d crewdb < /media/chh1/1818-305D/crewdb_bak.tar
```

The structure of the database has been recovered, so tables, views etc. except the actual data in the tables which has not been recovered.

Has anyone got an idea why this is and how to solve this.

Comment: You create a `tar` backup - you need to use `pg_restore` to restore it, not `psql`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the command you ran to restore your data is correct; on any case try to use the pq_restore as says from the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html) "restore a PostgreSQL database from an archive file created by pg_dump" that's the correct way to do it.

In my case I use `pg_dumpall -U user > backup.sql` then "`cat backup.sql | psql -U user database`"

I recommend you to check out the flags you're using on your pg_dump

Comment: Thanks J, I tried pg_restore -d crewdb -U username -C /media/chh1/1818-305D/crewdb_bak.tar and got the following error message: pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)